# Hibernate incrementing my inserts, causing duplicated rows in database

Tags: java, hibernate

I got some wierd things going on with my hibernate. When I use the below method, I get incremented my insert queries for each time I call it.

```
public void merge(Object entity) {
        session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();     
        session.merge(entity);
        session.getTransaction().commit();      
    }
```

I call the above from my servlet.

and get

```
Hibernate: insert into marker (organisation, projectId) values (?, ?)
```

if I call it again I get

```
Hibernate: insert into marker (organisation, projectId) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into marker (organisation, projectId) values (?, ?)
```

and a third time

```
Hibernate: insert into marker (organisation, projectId) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into marker (organisation, projectId) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into marker (organisation, projectId) values (?, ?)
```

and so forth. So it looks like each time I merge it'll call insert an additional time. I can see in my database records that it does increment the inserts aswell

I call my method from a servlet, if that can mean anything.

Answer (score 0):

Using saveOrUpdate apparently fixed it. I don't know what that caused.

Comment: saveOrUpdate is the solution.

This method calls save() or update() based on the operation. If the identifier exists, it will call update method else the save method will be called.